# Rmarkdown Cross-reference for Loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, r-markdown

I want to use rmarkdown to reference cross-references, but I'm generating plots in a loop. When I need to create cross-references, is there a fig.id that I can use for referencing?

```
x<-iris %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% names

{r i,fig.cap=paste(x,"vsPetal.Width")}
for (i in x[1:3]){
  p<-ggplot(iris, aes(!!sym(i), Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point()+ geom_xsideboxplot(orientation = "y") +theme_bw()
  print(p)
}

i need the answer for my question,thx a lot
```